# Installing opencv (C++) on Raspberry pi and other misc packages

Tags: raspbian, video, opencv, c++

I've been doing a fair amount of research in regards to installing opencv on to a raspberrian distro, but the problem is that there is far too many different methods to installing it and truth be told, im very new in regards to the linux system (Primary Windows User), i do understand how to use basic functionality and install basic programs like geany, but when it comes to something like opencv i am very unsure which way is the proper and effective way of installing opencv, or if anyone knows a fairly straight foward image (coding) editor would be well appricated to let me know.

as a side note im using the on board raspberry pi camera, could anyone recomend a C++ lib that is as useful as the python counterpart picamera as i have written up a python version of my desired project, but i would like to write it in C++ to actually see the speed, and effectiveness of each language (and for personal experience)

Running a type B rev 2 board

Thankyou for your time.

Answer (score 1):

To install software most folks can get by using `apt-get` to install software on Debian-style distributions (or the matching commands for other distros).

If you need a more recent OpenCV than available in Raspbian's `apt` you'll have to do is download the source code, unpack the compressed archive, and look for a file like `INSTALL` for how to compile from source. Many times compile from source would be something like...

```
./configure
make
make install
```

...with some repetitions of the configure step as you add software dependencies (hopefully available with `apt-get`).

Take a look at http://robertcastle.com/2014/02/installing-opencv-on-a-raspberry-pi/ for more details.

Comment: opencv is certainly available vi `apt-get`

Answer (score 1):

well it is fairly simple to install opencv

i have a simple command which will install opencv in your pi..

apt-get install libopencv-dev

or this

apt-get install $(apt-cache search opencv | awk '{print $1}' | tr '[:space:]' ' ')
this will do apt-cache for opencv and install all packages automatically.

also, If you are using Rpi camera, you can't do programming as in simple opencv.. using VideoCapture() .. and all

for doing that read this link. [Getting image data from raspberry pi camera module in OpenCV with Python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24262/getting-image-data-from-raspberry-pi-camera-module-in-opencv-with-python)

it is fairly simple.

Comment: What do you mean "you can't do programming as in simple opencv..."?  Using VL4, my picam functions fine in opencv after `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`.